# Is this bay tree dying?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, leaves, diseases, plant-care

This tree has just recently got these marks on all the leaves and there's no new growth this year. I'm afraid it's dying but is there anything I can do?[image][image]

Comment: A simple answer may be "yes, it is dying." Perhaps you can reword to ask what disease your plant is experiencing. Some information may be useful, such as how often do you water/ fertilize and when was it last transplanted. I would like to add a bounty to help your question get answered, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: No this plant is not 'dying'.  This plant is doing what it needs to do to protect itself from fungus.  It has gotten fungal spores splashed up on the leaves and if you look at the picture with a hole, it is trying to sequester fungus through the 'shot hole' process.

Comment: Too much water.  Did you use garden soil instead of potting soil?  What have you added to this system?  Mulch, fertilizer...how  do you water?  How long have you had this plant?

Comment: https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/bay/sweet-bay-leaf-spots.htm  Check this article and give us feedback.  I'll be back, got puppies to walk.  Answer these questions please.

Comment: I've had the plant several years, it was reported into a bigger pot last year using potting soil along with another one in an adjacent pot. The other plant is fine, has a good colour and fresh growth. They're both watered regularly if we get a dry spell but I live in Ireland so there's generally quite a bit of rain all year round.